# CouchDb one design doc with many views, or many design docs with a view

Tags: couchdb

I understand that disadvantage of keeping multiple views in the same design document. It would rebuild all the indexes from scratch if the design document is updated. What is the advantage of keeping multiple views in the same design document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It would rebuild all the indexes from scratch if the design document is updated.

Not from scratch. From my experience and from what I read about [views cleanup](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/maintenance/compaction.html#views-cleanup), I got that every view file is named after the hash of its definition.
So, when a design document is modified, every views are updated, you're right, BUT if neither their definition nor data have changed, the update is immediate. 
To get further, if you modify a view definition, and then change it back to the original definition, the old file will be used so that the view is not computed from scratch.

The problem is elsewhere. Every time a view is queried, all views are updated. From my experience, that can be a problem when you have both "small" views (with few emits per document, small keys, few or no values) and "big" views. Even if you just need the result from small views (e.g. in order to browse your data), you'll have to wait for big views computation to be done.

> What is the advantage of keeping multiple views in the same design document?

The main advantage of this is that views are parts of the same "app".
Wether it is a real Web application, or an HTTP API, you can have a coherent set of URIs through [rewrite](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/rewrites.html).

Another advantage, which is the "half full glass" part of the disadvantage that I mentioned previously, is that views get updated more often, and therefore are computed little by little. So there is more chance that, when you query a view, the update will be done faster.